# Jest tests are not found with correct TestRegex pattern

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am testing using Jest and am not sure why my tests cannot be found.

The current `testRegex` correctly shows I have 15 matches for my tests. The test also fails on a CircleCi running on GitHub.

Here is the error output that is run locally:

```
yarn test
yarn run v1.23.0-20220130.1630
warning ../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ jest --config --detectOpenHandles ./jest.config.js 
Webpack Resolver using: ./webpack.config.js
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /Users/anthonymadia/code/work/unirep-monorepo/packages/frontend
  85 files checked.
  testMatch:  - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /__utils__/ - 84 matches
  testRegex: (/__tests__/.*|(\.|/)(test|spec))\.js?$ - 15 matches
Pattern: ./jest.config.js - 0 matches
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is my jest config:

```
const ignores = ['/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__']

module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    roots: ['<rootDir>'],
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [...ignores],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
        '^.+\\.(gif|svg|ico|url|require)$': '<rootDir>/svgTransform.js',
    },
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.js?$',
    
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/__utils__/'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['tsx', 'js', 'ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '\\.(png|jpg|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|mp4)$':
            '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    },
    clearMocks: true,
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
        './src/__tests__/__utils__/setup.js',
    ],
    resolver: 'jest-webpack-resolver',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx}', '!src/tests'],
}
```

Comment: Even more strange is that I can test the files individually with no issues...